# Understanding move semantics with objects returned by a function

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

I came across the following program from learncpp.com as an example for understanding the move semantics. I tried to run this program and see how the program flow is working as explained in the tutorial.

But, I fail to understand it in the function call.

```
Auto_ptr4<Resource> generateResource()
{
    Auto_ptr4<Resource> res(new Resource);
    return res; // this return value will invoke the move constructor
}
```

Where it has been said that will use move constructor, but it is not doing that at all when I set a break point and debug.

Can anyone help me to understand why move constructor is not invoked here ? Does compiler eliding here ? If so, how to modify this so it will invoke move constructor. Please explain what is happening here.

Also, it would be great if you can share with some examples of where move constructor is called and how to use move constructors in place of copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Auto_ptr4
{
    T* m_ptr;
public:
    Auto_ptr4(T* ptr = nullptr)
    :m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    ~Auto_ptr4()
    {
        delete m_ptr;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    // Do deep copy of a.m_ptr to m_ptr
    Auto_ptr4(const Auto_ptr4& a)
    {
        m_ptr = new T;
        *m_ptr = *a.m_ptr;
    }

    // Move constructor
    // Transfer ownership of a.m_mptr to m_ptr
    Auto_ptr4(Auto_ptr4&& a)
    : m_ptr(a.m_ptr)
    {
        a.m_ptr = nullptr;
    }

    // Copy assignment
    // Do deep copy of a.m_ptr to m_ptr
    Auto_ptr4& operator=(const Auto_ptr4& a)
    {
        // Self-assignment detection
        if (&a == this)
            return *this;

        // Release any resource we're holding
        delete m_ptr;

        // Copy the resource
        m_ptr = new T;
        *m_ptr = *a.m_ptr;

        return *this;
    }

    // Move assignment
    // Transfer ownership of a.m_ptr to m_ptr
    Auto_ptr4& operator=(Auto_ptr4&& a)
    {
        // Self-assignment detection
        if (&a == this)
            return *this;

        // Release any resource we're holding
        delete m_ptr;

        // Transfer ownership of a.m_ptr to m_ptr
        m_ptr = a.m_ptr;
        a.m_ptr = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    T* operator->() const { return m_ptr; }
    bool isNull() const { return m_ptr == nullptr; }
};

class Resource
{
public:
    Resource() { std::cout << "Resource acquired\n"; }
    ~Resource() { std::cout << "Resource destroyed\n"; }
};

Auto_ptr4<Resource> generateResource()
{
    Auto_ptr4<Resource> res(new Resource);
    return res; // this return value will invoke the move constructor
}

int main()
{
    Auto_ptr4<Resource> mainres;
    mainres = generateResource(); // this assignment will invoke the move assignment

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Does compiler eliding here ?"* - It very well could be. That's a good thing, just so you know.

Comment: Could you say exactly what happens in your debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Auto_ptr4<Resource> generateResource()
{
    Auto_ptr4<Resource> res(new Resource);
    return res; // this return value will invoke the move constructor
}
```

Your code is written in a way that very much allows for copy elision. The C++ standard has an entire section devoted to just this use case.

[[class.copy.elision/1.1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1)

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function parameter or a variable introduced by the exception-declaration of a handler ([except.handle])) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function call's return object

If you want to prevent elision, you need to return an expression that cannot be elided legally. Fortunately it's rather easy in this case to also force a move constructor to be called:

```
Auto_ptr4<Resource> generateResource()
{
    Auto_ptr4<Resource> res(new Resource);
    return std::move(res); // this return value will invoke the move constructor
}
```

Since now the expression is not an automatic variable name, nor is `Auto_ptr4<Resource>&&` the same exactly as `Auto_ptr4<Resource>`. The c'tor isn't elided.

This is fine for learning purposes, but don't do it in real code. Copy elision is a very good thing that makes for more efficient code. Let the compiler do it for you when it can.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for all of you. I had to experiment with the code to understand what the compiler is eliding and when the copy/move constructors gets called.